# Why my account is locked from suggesting edits?

Tags: support

When and Why is an account not allowed to suggest edits..? (Not in META) Is there any limit for a day..? that after crossing it, the account wouldn't be allowed to suggest edits. Anyway most of the suggested edits are no accepted... Some get rejected and are edited by someone who reviews it..?

Comment: Again. This is a feature of the Stack Exchange network, and as such it is documented on the mother meta. Searching for `suggested edits [faq]` on the mother meta will be very helpful.

Comment: Dear @Crazy Buddy. A minor advice, which you may find useful: If you suggest edits, please make sure to follow good English writing style. This include e.g. not ending every sentences with ellipses...

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. But, It's a bit harder for me to speak & write English. It's not my native, but I'm still learning how to improve my *language skills*... :-)

Answer (score 2):

All the relevant information on suggested edits can be found at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) at Meta Stack Overflow.